# How to deal with negative values after subtracting the background?

Tags: correlation, nonparametric, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test, logarithm

I am working with Luminex data and have a question regarding the treatment of negative values after subtracting the background average. Specifically, I would like to know if these negative values need to be addressed before conducting statistical analyses such as non-parametric tests or correlations. If so, I am curious to learn about the best approach to handle them.

I have come across different methods employed by researchers to handle negative values. One approach involves adding a constant value (e.g., X) to the entire dataset, effectively converting the negative values into positive ones. Another approach I have observed is replacing negative values with a specific value, such as 0.

In addition, I am planning to transform my data to a log2 scale for visualization purposes in graphs. To achieve this, I have been replacing all negative values with 0.1. Interestingly, when applying the Kruskal-Wallis test, I obtained consistent results between the transformed data (with the negative values replaced by 0.1) and the unmodified data. According to what I found out, this was expected since the Kruskal-Wallis test primarily relies on the order of the data rather than the specific values. The modification I made did not alter the central tendency of the data, as the position of negative values remained the same. It's worth noting that 0.1 is much smaller than any positive value in my dataset. However, when I performed the two-sample Mann-Whitney U test (transitioning from three groups to two groups), the test results differed between the transformed and untransformed data.

I would greatly appreciate your guidance on this matter. I am seeking clarification on the best approach to handle such data. Understanding the appropriate methodology will greatly assist me in my analysis.

EDIT based on extra comments from the OP

Luminex is commonly used to measure analytes in the field of biological sciences, such as cytokines, antibodies, etc. In my case, it was used to measure antibody levels. To clarify your doubts about the blank, it involves averaging the blanks on the plate and subtracting that average from the duplicate averages of the samples. In other words, it's a constant value. There are some samples that naturally yield negative values. In my case, this can indicate either the absence of analyte in that sample or a high background signal.

These negative values cannot be excluded from the analysis as it would introduce bias. This situation is similar to when samples fall below the limit of detection, where researchers often use approaches like replacing them with a constant value. However, I have also come across discussions that suggest this may not be the best approach. I'm uncertain whether negative values should be included in the analysis. For the statistical analysis, I am using the actual values, including the negative values.

To visualize the data, I have adopted an approach commonly seen in several papers, which involves replacing negative values with a positive value (lower and distinct from the actual positive values) to allow for plotting the log2 of the results. However, I still have doubts about whether it is correct to use negative values or if I should replace them with half the average background value, as advised for the limit of detection. Yet, I have also encountered comments that disagree with this approach.

All I know is that I cannot ignore the negative values as they reflect the lack of analyte signal in the samples under the run conditions. The statistical analyses I am conducting are non-parametric, including Wilcoxon tests, Kruskal tests, correlation analysis (Spearman), and PCA. I appreciate your guidance on how to handle these data concerns.

END OF EDIT

Comment: The people who most commonly experience this problem are in radiological sciences, where almost invariably background must be measured and subtracted. They don't use any of the methods described here due to their bias and arbitrariness. How you handle such data depends on the analyses you need to do.  For instance, some analyses explicitly model the background and therefore would suffer from any preliminary treatment.  Other analyses might not care, such as rank-based non-parametric comparisons.  For the best approach (or even a good one), please tell us more about what you want to accomplish.

Comment: You've added several extra comments in reply to my answer, which I've edited in here. I'll let my answer stand  for the moment, but I hope it will be superseded by a much better answer from someone closer to your field.

Answer (score 1):

Subtracting the mean, or any other constant, before calculating correlations, or anything based directly on correlations, or ranks, or anything based on ranks, is or should be harmless as the correlations or ranks are not affected at all by whether you first subtract a mean, or any other constant. That can be demonstrated either through algebra or through practical examples.

Subtracting the mean before taking logarithms on the other hand  strikes me as absurd to a high degree, and adding some constant to make all values positive is another wrong that doesn't make a right. Just occcasionally if the lowest value is zero, there is an *ad hoc* rationale for something like $\log(x + 1)$ or if there are negative, zero, and positive values there is an occasional case for something like $\text{sign}(x) \log(1 + |x|)$. But even such transformations have to be defended in each case, especially as there is no inherent magic in the constant $1$: the problem is why $1$ should be used and not any other constant that makes all logarithms calculatable. (I set aside the fact that logarithms are defined mathematically for negative numbers, which does not seem helpful statistically.)

Replacing all negative values by some arbitrary constant also seems bizarre unless there is some substantive rationale. Even if negative values mean somehow missing or irrelevant, then the remedy seems to be to ignore them as such. It's correct e.g. that replacing a minority of negative values with some positive constant may not change the median. But the message is that the procedure does not always do much harm, not that it is a good idea.

Logarithms always are well defined if all values are positive and may even be useful if they correspond to some physical (biological, psychological, economic, whatever) phenomenology whereby to a good approximation processes are multiplicative, say that exponential growth or decline is at least a reference case.

Comment: I think you may have misunderstood OP's goal.

They are subtracting a background/no sample/"blank" measurement from other measurements made on specimens. After removing that offset, they want to describe changes as doubling/halving relatives to some *other* control (sample with/without drug, say).

I think this is not totally bonkers, but the obvious solution doesn't work in the presence of noise.

Comment: Possibly. but background average is to me an average, or else the wording should be changed. And subtraction of an average can be expected to leave some negative values in its wake (unless anyone explains that  the background average is itself negative). Indeed the OP is telling us that they have to deal with negative values in a variety of puzzling ways.

Comment: I happily confess that I don't know what Luminex data are and didn't try to find out. If understanding that is vital to the question, please put the explanation in the question. I am completely willing to delete or modify this answer if it is based on misunderstanding.